# React native - onPressIn cancel on scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to invoke function imediatly when user touch the TouchableWithoutFeedback, but if i use OnPressIn i have problem with scrolling. When user scroll - he activate the function. OnPress event on other hand is slow. What i need use? I want when user touch TouchableOpacity view to fire the function without need of release the button. OnPressIn with proper scroll functionality.

The items are inside FlatList. Every item need to have onPressIn and to be able to scroll without trigger onPressIn.

Comment: what you mean by ```I have problem with scrolling```? Could you share some code.

Comment: When i try to scroll inside flatlist with items that have onPressIn event, the scroll works but i trigger onPressIn on the item when i'm scrolling. When i have onPress - i can scroll inside list items without triggering the function, but when i have onPressIn - there is problem.

Comment: If possible could you share your code? Then I might be able to help you.